# How to bulk import bookmarks into Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, bookmarks, field-codes

I can add a field anywhere with `CTRL F9`, then write inside braces: `SET Test "this is a test" \* MERGEFORMAT` and use it with the field `REF Test` which is displayed `this is a test`. Note: I am not sure "bookmark" is the write term for it because then it is confusing with HTML bookmarks, so I use the general Word term "field".

But I need to import hundreds of such fields. I have tried to prepare them as a long string like: `{SET Test "this is a test" \* MERGEFORMAT}{SET Test2 "this is test 2" \* MERGEFORMAT}` but these braces are not Word ones for fields and of course it does not work.

So I have saved the document as an XML document with two bookmarks set the Word way, one by one. To be able to locate them easily, the first one is preceded by "xxxxx", the second one by "yyyyy" and ends with "zzzzz". Here is the XML code excerpt:

```
xxxxx</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="00CB7095"><w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="00CB7095"><w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> SET  Test "ceci est un test" \* MERGEFORMAT </w:instrText></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="00CB7095"><w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/></w:r><w:bookmarkStart w:id="9" w:name="Test"/><w:r w:rsidR="00CB7095"><w:rPr><w:noProof/></w:rPr><w:t>ceci est un test</w:t></w:r><w:bookmarkEnd w:id="9"/><w:r w:rsidR="00CB7095"><w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/></w:r><w:r><w:t>yyyyy</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="00CB7095"><w:rPr><w:noProof/></w:rPr><w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="00CB7095"><w:rPr><w:noProof/></w:rPr><w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> SET  Test2 "second test" \* MERGEFORMAT </w:instrText></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="00CB7095"><w:rPr><w:noProof/></w:rPr><w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/></w:r><w:bookmarkStart w:id="10" w:name="Test2"/><w:r w:rsidR="00CB7095"><w:rPr><w:noProof/></w:rPr><w:t>second test</w:t></w:r><w:bookmarkEnd w:id="10"/><w:r w:rsidR="00CB7095"><w:rPr><w:noProof/></w:rPr><w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:noProof/></w:rPr><w:t>zzzzz
```

So I have added after "zzzzz":

```
</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="00CB7095"><w:rPr><w:noProof/></w:rPr><w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="00CB7095"><w:rPr><w:noProof/></w:rPr><w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> SET  Test3 "third test" \* MERGEFORMAT </w:instrText></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="00CB7095"><w:rPr><w:noProof/></w:rPr><w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/></w:r><w:bookmarkStart w:id="100" w:name="Test3"/><w:r w:rsidR="00CB7095"><w:rPr><w:noProof/></w:rPr><w:t>second test</w:t></w:r><w:bookmarkEnd w:id="100"/><w:r w:rsidR="00CB7095"><w:rPr><w:noProof/></w:rPr><w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:noProof/></w:rPr><w:t>aaaaa
```

I could see that the last id used in my document is `w:id="94"`, then I have decided to add new ids starting at 100.

When I open the XML document in Words and display fields contents, it looks good:

```
xxxxx{SET Test "this is a test" \* MERGEFORMAT}yyyyy{SET Test2 "this is test 2" \* MERGEFORMAT}zzzzz{SET Test3 "this is test 3" \* MERGEFORMAT}aaaaa
{REF Test1}, {REF Test2}, {REF Test3}
```

And when I switch to reading mode, it works:

```
xxxxxyyyyyzzzzzaaaaa

second test, ceci est un test, third test.
```

But is there a simplier way to do it?

Comment: First, you seldom want the \* MERGEFORMAT switch. Often the \* CHARFORMAT switch is more useful. Do you have your bookmark names and contents in an Excel or CVS file? If you do, it is likely this could be done using vba (a macro). This would not be a beginner programming exercise. See Working With Bookmarks on this page: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA.htm.

Comment: Is there a way to define something like a dictionary with key/value pairs directly in the word document? The document shall be self-content.

Comment: @lalebarde there probably isn't a "simpler" way than the one that you worked out for yourself and which seems to work. If you can code, there are plenty of ways you could do this. For key/value pairs, depnds on what you are trying to do. If you can use VBA, you can set up Document Variables, which are hidden variables with a name and a text value, and insert a value using a DOCVARIABLE field and the variable name.